# Is it possible to autoconvert all values that mybatis get from db to strings?

Tags: java, string, mybatis

Im getting several rows, from my query result, which consist of several column values, some column values are string type, other is Long. I want all of them in string map, but getting class cast exception. Long cant be casted to String.

```
<select id="someId" resultType="HashMap">
```

and

```
LinkedList<HashMap<String, String>> someId(@Param("clientsIdsStr") String clientsIdsStr);
```

I want to get all the columns values as string values in a result HashMap, how can i achieve it?

[This is what returned map contains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxEw9.png)